# Does $|e^{f(z)}| = 1$ on parallel lines imply that $f$ is constant?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f : \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ be a holomorphic function. Suppose that for some $a<b<c \in \mathbb R$ we have
$$
|e^{f(z)}| = 1
$$
for all $z = x+iy, x \in \mathbb R, y \in \{ a,b,c \}$. That is, $|e^f|$ is constant one for such $x$ and $y$. Can we conclude that $e^f$ is globally constant, i.e. $f(z)=iu$ for some real $u$? I was thinking to apply a Phragmen Lindelöf argument, but failed.

Comment: Use identity theorem.

Comment: Not  clear how the identity theorem can help here.

Comment: I think that schwarz reflection principle implies there are infinitely many such parallel lines and $e^{f}$ would be periodic

Comment: @Keplerto Thanks for your comment! If e.g. $a=0$ and $b=1$ then the function $|e^f|$ would satisfy  $|e^{f(\cdot + i)}| = e^f$ using schwarz reflection principle? Is this what you mean with periodicity? So $|e^f|$ is one-periodic in direction of the imaginary axis?

Comment: @user975628 I think in fact you can get that $f$ is periodic (it is in the given answer). If  $a=0, b=1$ then from the assumption, $$\Im z = 0, 1 \implies \Re f(z) = 0,$$ so by Schwarz principle you get $f(\overline z) = \overline{f(z)}$ and $f(\overline z) = \overline{f(z+2i)}.$ Thus  $$f(z+2i) = f(z).$$ So yes, $f$ is periodic in the imaginary direction with period $2i$, and not just $e^f$

Answer (score 8):

Write $f(x+yi) = u(x,y) + v(x,y)i$.
Suppose $a=-\pi, b=0, c=\pi$.
Consider $u(x,y)=\exp(x)\sin(y)$.
One can check that $u$ is harmonic, and thus one can find a $v$ such that $f$ is holomorphic.
Furthermore, on the prescribed lines one can check that $|e^{f(z)}|=1$.
So no, $f$ need not be constant.

Comment: +1 Looks good to me.

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks for calling out the fallacious argument earlier.

Comment: I am frequently wrong.

Comment: By the way, we find that the harmonic conjugate of $u$ is, up to a  constant, $v(x,y) = -e^x\cos(y)$ thus $f(z) = -ie^z$ and indeed, for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $\exp(-ie^{x + 2i\pi n}) = \exp(-ix)$ has a norm that equals one.

Comment: Well done. What fails with the arguments that have been tried is that $f$ is not bounded on the strip.